# SSIS OLE-DB Source unable to use parameters

Tags: parameters, ssis, oledb

This seems to be a common question, but I am hoping someone can finally give me an explanation that makes sense.  I have various queries that extract data from CRM systems that I am trying to pass a parameter to.  One of them is a SQL Server 2012 DB running on the same box as my reporting database

doing

DECLARE @days int

SET @Days = ?

Works,  doing the exact same thing on a sql server 2003 box running on a different physical box fails with a parameters could not be extracted from SQL.  N.b. these are different databases and the queries are different but I am not using sub queries (I am using unions though)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same case for parameters. like:

```
DECLARE @days int

SET @days = ?
```

Instead of

```
DECLARE @days int

SET @Days = ?
```